# how to make 4 9's equal 20?

Tags: math

9  9  9  9=20， you can add +,-,x,/ or () between the number. how to make them equal.

Comment: Your question does not belong on StackOverflow. Check out math.stackexchange.com. Also note that nobody will solve your homework for you.

Comment: There are no solutions from 4 nines, you can manage it from 5. I put it through a solver and know there are no solutions. You haven't said we can use square root signs or factorial signs or turn them over to become sixes although you could do that with fact(sqrt(9)) anyway. If I can do that I can make it to 20

Comment: With other symbols: 9 + 9 + (sqrt(9))!/sqrt(9) = 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer even though this has nothing to do with development

(99) / 9 + 9 = 20